# How do you embed a Processing sketch in a HTML page on Google App Engine

Tags: javascript, html, google-app-engine, embed, processing

I would like to put my Processing sketches online onto my web page on Google App Engine.

I found a way to put the Processing JS Javascript code straight into the HTML file.
If I save this file on my computer and open it in a browser it works!

However when I copy this code onto my google app engine I just get a blank box.

Does anyone know a little about GAE, and why this might be?
the code in my HTML file is this.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Mouse2D \ Examples \ Processing.org</title>

    <!-- script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script -->
    <script src="processing.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
    <!-- script src="http://processing.org/javascript/modernizr-2.6.2.touch.js" type ="!text/javascript"></script -->
</head>

<body>
    <label>This is above the Processing Canvas</label>
    <br>
    <div class="proc">
    <script type="application/processing"> 
    void setup() 
    {
      size(640, 360);
      noStroke();
      rectMode(CENTER);
    }

    void draw() 
    {   
      background(51); 
      fill(255, 204);
      rect(mouseX, height/2, mouseY/2+10, mouseY/2+10);
      fill(255, 204);
      int inverseX = width-mouseX;
      int inverseY = height-mouseY;
      rect(inverseX, height/2, (inverseY/2)+10, (inverseY/2)+10);
    }

    </script>
    <canvas width="640" height="360"></canvas>
    <div>This is below the canvas</div>


</body>
```

I got this far by looking at how they did it on the Processing Examples page, here http://processing.org/examples/mouse2d.html

I am trying to embed it on my wiki at http://tb21g09.appspot.com/processing
If anyone has succeeded in embedding a Processing sketch in a webpage I'd love to know how!

I understand you can also put the javascript file onto the web server and then call that from the html file. Im not sure how to do that, this seems easier and quicker to try.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to deploy an HTML file with your App Engine app such that you can load the file directly into a browser by visiting a URL, you can use App Engine's "static files" feature.  To do this, you configure a static file handler in your `app.yaml` file that associates URL paths with file paths:

```
handlers:
- url: /pages
  static_dir: pages
```

This example says that everything in my app's `pages/...` directory should be served directly when the user visits the corresponding `/pages/...` URL.  These files are served verbatim, and do not interact with the server code of your app.  More information on configuring static file handlers: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Python_app_yaml_Static_file_handlers

You mentioned that you want some Processing JS code to appear in a wiki application.  If there is server code that is producing the page in which you want the Processing JS code to appear, you'll need to do something other than static files.  In general, the text that you want to appear on the app-generated page needs to be available to the app somehow, and there needs to be app logic to emit it with the page.  To give a more specific answer, we'd need to know more about your application.

For example, maybe the Processing JS code goes in a file, and the app code is instructed to read from that file and insert its contents into the middle of the dynamically generated page.  Maybe the page is generated from a "template" file, and the Processing JS code can be inserted into it.  If it's a wiki application and the contents of the page are stored as data, then maybe the Processing JS code needs to be added to the data used to make the page, such as with the wiki's page editing tool.

(If you need more specific advice, please amend the question to say more about how your wiki app works.)